# Is it possible to Merge Image Files using KTA SDK?

Tags: kofax

Using KTA API I am trying to create a job document (CreateJobWithDocuments) for list of images. I want all images should be part of single document collection. Is it possible to achieve this using KTA API or do I need to use third party tool to merge files.

***For example : ImageFilePath1 (2 pages), ImageFilePath2 (3 Pages), ImageFilePath3 (1 Page) should reside under single document with 6 pages.***

Answer (score 0):

The KTA API does not provide general purpose functions for working with arbitrary image files, such as you have before you have called CreateJobWithDocuments.  If you are sure you need to merge them prior to submitting them into KTA, then you need to do that in your own/third-party code.

The KTA API does provide functionality for merging documents within KTA [CaptureDocumentService.MergeDocuments](https://docshield.kofax.com/KTA/en_US/7.8.0-dpm5ap0jk8/help/API/latest/class_agility_1_1_sdk_1_1_services_1_1_capture_document_service.html#ab8391c9e2f1e59e20246bcb38536ff59).  One caveat is that if the document source was not an image, such as PDF/docx/etc, then they need to be converted to TIFF first, so use a Document Conversion activity, then a .NET activity to call the Merge API.

So, given that you want to submit multiple files that need to be merged into one document, consider this approach:

- Treat them as separate documents for the call to [CreateJobWithDocuments](https://docshield.kofax.com/KTA/en_US/7.8.0-dpm5ap0jk8/help/API/latest/class_agility_1_1_sdk_1_1_services_1_1_job_service.html#afc5a2c3d8eb2b0b9c9d4f5cf30a91e38) so that they are separate documents at the start of your Job’s process
- If you will including other formats, start the process with a Document Conversion activity to create TIFF pages
- Then call the [MergeDocuments](https://docshield.kofax.com/KTA/en_US/7.8.0-dpm5ap0jk8/help/API/latest/class_agility_1_1_sdk_1_1_services_1_1_capture_document_service.html#ab8391c9e2f1e59e20246bcb38536ff59) API from in the process to merge your files into one document.
- Then after that point in the process you have your single merged document for the rest of the process steps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. We are writing a custom application using the SDK. Is it possible to achieve that.  By saying that, we will have multiple documents in the same scenario.  

Document 1 : ImageFilePath1 (2 pages), ImageFilePath2 (3 Pages), ImageFilePath3 (1 Page)

*Document 2* : ImageFilePath1 (2 pages), ImageFilePath2 (3 Pages), ImageFilePath3 (1 Page)

Also could you please touch more with the merge documents. Since I am creating the jobs in a separate .NET API, how can merge documents. To merge docs we need doc ids. Not sure how to get the doc ids. Bit lost here. Any help?